# How to Share Video in a Lync Conversation using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, share, lync

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfyy5v2c7vxrnb6/Lync%202013%20Control%20PowerPoint%20and%20whiteboard%20sharing%20sessions%20from%20a%20WPF%20app.zip?dl=0) is my project so far. I think you can only run it if you have Microsoft Lync installed on your computer.This is a WPF app by the way.

It have several features including creating a Lync conversation, sharing a powerpoint, and sharing a whiteboard. So Instead of sharing a Powerpoint, I want to share a video file.

So, just like how the "Share PowerPoint" button works on my project, you have to type the full path of the powerpoint file you want to share, then click that button. Then that powerpoint file will show up on the lync conversation you previously created. it's like a shareable content.

But now I want to type the file path of a video instead and share a Video file on Lync conversation, just like that -sharePowerPoint- feature/button in my project. Any ideas? Code Samples for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the resource/application sharing modality to share a video playing locally but the quality would probably be terrible and you would have to play it live.

The problem is there is no specific `ModalityAction` for video like there is for PowerPoint and Whiteboard content. I think the only way to share video as content aside from using the resource/application approach is to attach it as a file to the meeting, which would not present it.